# android: If Activity killed, on restart what happens?

Tags: android

Lets say, activity A starts activity B with a intend and passes data in the extra. Then the system kills my **process** because of memory issues. Then lets say my app is brought to the foreground by some mean, also assume activity A is the launch activity in the manifest, then will it bring up activity B (possibly bringing up A first) since it was the last Activity.

If it brings up Activity B then in the onCreate() do I have access to my original intend or do I have any way to know that the system restarted my activity?

Answer (score 0):

If activity killed - you will get activity A - I suppose in your maifest file you have only one activity with intent filter `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

Comment: I meant the system kills my process. From what I know when this happens then the system brings back the last activity of the process

Comment: You can check this by killing process manually - in preferences - applications - in your app info there is button force stop.

Comment: Thanks. If you kill the process manually with force stop then it starts the application from the begening. But I read that if the system, to conserve memory, can kill the process and then bring back the last visible activity of the app.

Comment: And how can you return to activity? Launch icon start activity, that marked as `LAUNCHER` in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

"Then the system kills my process because of memory issues and restarts. Then it restores the last activity, which is B."

This is wrong and you should remove it from your question.

If the system needs memory and kills your activity's process, it doesn't restore it again. It can be restarted, but then it will start at the activity that has a launch intent defined in the manifest (or by a broadcastlistener, alarmmanager or notification).

I understand your question as:

If an activity has been removed from the activity stack (because the system needed memory), and you restart it, do you have access to the original calling intent.

Interpreted like that, it is easy to see that the answer is no. Since the only way to relaunch a killed activity is using a new Intent, the old intent will naturally not be available.

BUT

If you want access to data from an instance of your activity that was killed, you need to save it in OnSaveInstanceState. The saved state will then be provided in the OnCreate method the next time your activity is launched.

See [Process Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle): 3. A background activity

Using that, you could save the original calling intent, and use that to recreate the activity. I would consider the effect of this on the user experience very carefully before doing this though.

Comment: I edited my post. So is it possible for activity B to come up by any possible mean. I am bringing this up because I read people say that B, since its the last activity can come up and its not initialized properly, just wanted to make sure. Also I am not sure if OnSaveInstanceState is always called when activity is destroyed.